# Why am I getting the invalid syntax?

Tags: pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I am new to Machine learning. I am trying to plot the input data.
but it gives me syntax error:

"C:\Users\shafi\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_14876/3654013207.py", line 1
plt.scatter(year,per capita income (US$),color='blue',marker='+')
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df=pd.read_csv('E:/CV (ALL FOR JOB)/ALL PROJECTS/5. IMAGE DETECTION/canada.csv')
df
df.head(3)

%matplotlib inline 
plt.xlabel('year',fontsize=20)
plt.ylabel('per capita income (US$)',fontsize=20)
plt.scatter(df.year,df.per capita income (US$),color='blue',marker='+')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`per capita income (US$)` is not a valid [python identifier](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers):

```
plt.scatter(df.year, df['per capita income (US$)'], color='blue', marker='+')
```

You should avoid dot-notation if your column names are not valid python identifiers and use `[]` to avoid `SyntaxError` exception.